# How to Use check box list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to display check box list with more than one options. User must select minimum one check box, user can select more than one check boxes.

I want to store values of all check boxes (selected) in one field as a string(Data base) with coma separated. This is not mandatory, mandatory is need to store multiple values of each selected check box. Alternate solutions are welcome.

> Model

```
public class Member
{
      public string Member_VehicalType { get; set; }
      public IList<SelectListItem> Member_VehicalType_List { get; set; }
```

> Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Member objMemberModel = new Member();            
        List<SelectListItem> vehical_Types = new List<SelectListItem>();
        vehical_Types.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Two Wheeler", Value = "1" });
        vehical_Types.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Four Wheeler", Value = "2" });
        objMemberModel.Member_VehicalType_List = vehical_Types;
        return View(objMemberModel);
```

How do I create view with `@Html.CheckBoxFor(` or `@Html.CheckBox(`

Comment: `SelectListItem` is for use in a dropdownlist (not a checkbox). Create a view model for your collection

Comment: Take a look at the ASP.Net Identity samples that make use of `SelectList`s and then output checkboxes from it. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenMuecke Can you please give some code snippet for view model for collection?

Comment: Create a view model with 3 properties (say) `int ID; string Name; bool IsSelected;` then (say) `public List<VehicleOption> Options { get; set; }` and use a `for` loop to bind a checkbox to the `IsSelected` property

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to deal with `SelectListItem` as a checkbox-list. I came up with the following HtmlExtensions, which might be helpful. These extensions provide the same functionality as the `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => ...);`

Usage:  `@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.ModelMemberToPutValueIn, Model.Member_VehicalType_List)`

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var listName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        items = GetCheckboxListWithDefaultValues(metaData.Model, items);

        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxList(listName, items, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string listName, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        if (items == null) return null;

        var container = new TagBuilder("div");
        container.AddCssClass("checkbox-list");
        container.MergeAttribute("id", HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(listName));

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var id = HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(String.Join(".", listName, item.Text));
            var div = new TagBuilder("div");
            div.AddCssClass("checkbox");

            var cb = new TagBuilder("input");
            cb.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            cb.MergeAttribute("id", id);
            cb.MergeAttribute("name", listName);
            cb.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value ?? item.Text);
            if (item.Selected) cb.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.MergeAttribute("for", id);
            label.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);
            label.InnerHtml = item.Text;

            div.InnerHtml = cb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + label;
            container.InnerHtml += div;
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(container.ToString());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCheckboxListWithDefaultValues(object defaultValues, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
    {
        var defaultValuesList = defaultValues as IEnumerable;
        if (defaultValuesList == null) return selectList;

        var values = from object value in defaultValuesList select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        var selectedValues = new HashSet<string>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var newSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in selectList)
        {
            item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) : selectedValues.Contains(item.Text);
            newSelectList.Add(item);
        }

        return newSelectList;
    }
}
```